# Wait for a website finished loading all javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to catch the HTML Code of a simple website:

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<< MY URL >>"]];
 NSError *error;

 NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&error];

 if(data){
    NSLog(@"Data:\n%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
            }
            else{
                //Error
            }
```

I tried some other ways of getting the html code, but the requested data is always incomplet. These are some of the last lines of the code:

```
</script></div>
<!-- INDEX -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<< SourceName >>.js"></script>
```

I think, the embedded Javascript didn't load. Is there a way, to wait until the script did load completely and to catch the whole content after that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Synchronous request you are only capturing the Data for your URL.
So your connection request returned with just the HTML.

You need to use the WebView to load the javascript. You can then read the javascript from the Webview methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that already with the Webview Delegate Method 

`webView.request.URL,[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"]);`

Still only the html..

Comment: @StefanLiesendahl That tries to run the JS. Instead, load the HTML into the webview.

Comment: One way you can do is to download the HTML from the website and then parse the HTML to find the links inside the HTML and download them further. Here is a link to that might help you parse the HTMl file.  https://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios